# Save Visual Studio that already installed

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, installation

I installed visual studio with windows 10 sdk and tools . (with many difficulty!)
Now I want to save this to use another computer and without need to download sdk again.

Comment: You would have had a shot at it if you'd have downloaded the ISO.  That's kinda too late now.

Comment: Or had downloaded the installer using `vs_setup /layout` first.

Comment: You could clone the whole computer...

Comment: But with ISO file , I won't have sdk 10 with tools and I must download again it!